# Does The many world Interpretation sneakily get rid of the observer by including it in the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

For example in the double slit experiment, the two states are electron goes right and observer observes it going right and electron goes left and observer observes it going left each having a coefficient of 1/√2. So are we, by including the observer in the wave function, getting rid of the statement that is often stated in Copenhagen that if electron is observed to pass through one slit, it is no longer in a superposition?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little more complicated than that as there are two distinct concepts involved.

In quantum mechanics it is normal for systems to be in a superposition of states. For example the electron passing through the slits is in a superposition of passing through both slits. But we never observe anything to be in a superposition. If we put detectors by the slits then we find two things:

1. we always find the particle going through one slit or the other - never both
2. which slit the particle goes through is random

So we have to answer two questions:

1. why do we never see a superposition?
2. what decides which slit we detect the particle passing through?

Question (1) is answered by a process called [quantum decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence). Technically this process diagonalises the density matrix. In effect it removes the superposition so the system is on one of the eigenstates, though it doesn't specify which one.

Question (2) is answered by the Many Worlds idea. Following decoherence we get a branch into different worlds for the different observed eigenstates.

The interaction with the observer is really part of decoherence, so it isn't true to say that Many Worlds gets rid of the observer by including them in the wavefunction, though admittedly it's common to use *Many Worlds* in a loose way to mean both processes.

We should provide the obligatory warning that the popular science idea of Many Worlds is at best a caricature. The idea of universes splitting into two is nowhere to be found in Everett's thesis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it cleared up most of the questions i had about MWI. Just two questions, 1} In MWI does the Wave Function give us the probability of observing a state in our universe while also acknowledging that even after observation the Particle is still in superposition from a multi-universal perspective(If some multi-dimensional being looks at the electron he would say it went right in universe A and left in universe B?) If this is true, why don't the different universes interfere with each other even after the observation?